# Self-signed certificates and ephemeral Diffie–Hellman key exchange protocol

Tags: attacks, man-in-the-middle, diffie-hellman

If we use a self-signed certificate, is ephemeral Diffie–Hellman key exchange protocol vulnerable to a man in the middle attack?

Comment: Is there anything else you'd like me to add to my answer?

Answer (score 4):

Unless the users connecting to your site have imported your self-certificate from a trusted source, then yes, you will be vulnerable to MITM attacks. The reason for this is that an attacker could use his own self-signed certificate, and there would be no way for end users to tell that it is not the correct one.

Don't use a self-signed certificate. Teaching users to ignore the browser warnings and click through teaches them bad habits. If you don't want to spend money on a certificate, you can use a free service like [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/). This is a CA which provides free domain validation-based certificates.